# Disabling a checkbox when another checkbox is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am trying to disable the thin and crispy checkbox when traditional checkbox is clicked. I have these in a group due to me enabling the whole group when the numericUpDown value is set to 1. When I click traditional checkbox, it doesn't disable the thin and crispy checkbox. I am using windows form application

**Code**

```
        private void NudQuantity1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (NudQuantity1.Value == 0)
            {
                gbCheesePizza.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gbCheesePizza.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (CBXTraditional1.Checked == true)
            {
                CBXthinandcrispy1.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

When I run this code outside of a groupbox, it works perfectly.

Comment: Is `NudQuantity1_ValueChanged` called when the user clicks traditional checkbox?

Comment: Is the parent container of the checkbox disabled? If it is disabled you cannot make a child of this container enabled.

Comment: Also I wish to understand another point. If you have to choose an unique option between _traditional_ and _thin and crispy_ why do you use checkboxes instead of radiobuttons that are specifically designed to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this block should be inside the event handler

```cs
if (CBXTraditional1.Checked == true)
{
    CBXthinandcrispy1.Enabled = false;
}
```

It means that, provided you've got no other event handling for the checkboxes, this code will only be executed when you change the value of `NudQuantity1` so it won't execute anything when you click the checkboxes afterwards.

Try use radio buttons as [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) mentioned. They do this for you.